# How does method redirection takes place in super class and base class?

Tags: java, superclass, base-class

```
class HouseHold extends Customer {

    public void requestCoupon() {
        Transaction();
        CouponCount = 20;
    }

    public double Transaction () {
        Payment += CouponPayment;
        return Payment;
    }
}


class GCustomer extends HouseHold { 

      public double Transaction () {
        Payment += DisCPayment;
        return Payment;
    }
}
```

I'm making an object (A) of the `GCustomer` class and I need to request coupon using the super class (`A.requestCoupon();`). What I'm stuck at is that the method `requestCoupon()` calls the `Transaction()` method and if `A` calls the request method will it call the one in super class or in base class?

Comment: add a sysouts inside methods and see

Comment: This might be of assistance: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html (Ps: This is something you can *easily* test yourself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphism is enforced dynamically (at runtime) based on the actual type of the object that is calling the method. It relies on the ability to assign an object of a subclass to a reference of the superclass.

Also, notice that when you have an instance method in a class and you call another method inside that instance method without using an explicit reference (the `reference.method()` syntax), then the call is made through an implicit `this` reference which refers to the object actually making the call (in this case, the derived class).

Answer (score 0):

It will call from GCustomer class, once that the method Transaction() was overrided.